# Striping in ArcMap picture symbol PDF export?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, symbology, pdf

I made two PNGs to use as point symbols for state highways. When I export them, the symbols have stripes.

[image: Highway Symbol 1]
[image: Highway Symbol 2]
[image: Highway Symbol PNG 1]
[image: Highway Symbol PNG 2]

I've tried embedding all document fonts and converting marker symbols to polygons with similar results.

How I can export these symbols properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Picture Symbol option to "Vectorize layers with bitmap markers/fills" and see if that resolves the issue.

[image]

Maybe also try unchecking the box for “Compress Vector Graphics.”

Comment: I tried Vectorizing layers right after I posted...same result. This map takes about half an hour to export... le sigh

Trying compressing vectors now. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Tried not compressing vector graphics... Still stripey.

Comment: @IanYau Given that the export takes a half hour, perhaps this is due to a memory issue - I could be wrong. Have you tried sliding the JPEG quality bar all the way to Low to see what happens?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still the same results. It's a large map with a feathered fade-to-white effect that I expect to export slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what cause the striping effect or how to prevent this but one way to solve your problem is to use a vector format for your symbol, either by creating an .emf image (it's the vector image format arcgis can use instead of more common .svg) or by using a font symbol (typical instalation of arcgis come with lot of 'cartographic' font the ''ESRI Shield'' should get you close of your exemple)

Comment: I've tried this as well using Inkscape, but cannot get the background transparency to work. The background shows up black using the EMF.